# Label or tag for questions

Tags: labels, exam, tags

I am making mini question banks on different chapters of physics. For this, I am using the 'exam' class. what I need is the following:

I want to put some information for my own use against each of the questions. For example, year, difficulty level (hard, easy etc.), topic name and such labels. I need the ability to print or suppress printing these labels depending on situations.

Following is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}


\unframedsolutions
\printanswers

\begin{document}
        \section{ABC}
    \begin{questions}

        \question This is question 1 ? 
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 1
        \end{solution}

        \question This is question 2
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 2
        \end{solution}
        \question This is Question 3
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 3
        \end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

What is want is like below :

```
    \begin{document}
    \section{ABC}
    \begin{questions}

        \question This is question 1 ? \label{difficult, 2009, Light}
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 1
        \end{solution}

        \question This is question 2 \label{moderate, 2019, Sound}
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 2
        \end{solution}
        \question This is Question 3
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 3
        \end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

And as we use '\printanswers', I should be able to use '\printlabels' or '\noprintlabels'

How to achieve this ?

Comment: `\label` is already used by LaTeX for something else.  You should come up with a new name.

Comment: Yes, any other name instead of 'label'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this??

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\newcommand\printqtags{\def\qtag##1{\par\textbf{Tag: (##1)}}}
\newcommand\noprintqtags{\def\qtag##1{}}

\unframedsolutions
\printanswers
\printqtags
    \begin{document}
    \section{ABC}
    \begin{questions}

        \question This is question 1 ? \qtag{difficult, 2009, Light}
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 1
        \end{solution}

        \question This is question 2 \qtag{moderate, 2019, Sound}
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 2
        \end{solution}
        \question This is Question 3
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 3
        \end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\printqtags` changed to `\noprintqtags`, the result becomes

[image]

Comment: Exactly. how can I print those labels in a separate line or paragraph below the question, just like the solution environment with a heading like that in 'Solution'?

Comment: @cosmicraga Something like `\newcommand\printqtags{\def\qtag##1{\par\textbf{Tag: (##1)}}}`?  If so, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Perfect. :) Please edit your answer.

Comment: Hi, I have another feature request I think is related to your answer. I like the tag feature attached to each question. But are there any mechanism for me to count how many questions or grades for each tag. For example, I would like to see how many questions are for tag "Light", and how much score are for the tag "difficult". This will be benefit for a teacher to make a statistics of his exam. Thanks.

Comment: @ollydbg23 Perhaps this approach would work.  Define categories: `\newcounter{QTAGdifficult}
\newcounter{QTAGmoderate}
\newcommand\moderate{\stepcounter{QTAGmoderate}moderate}
\newcommand\difficult{\stepcounter{QTAGdifficult}difficult}`.  Then, in the invocation, use the macro instead of the word: `\question This is question 1 ? \qtag{\difficult, 2009, Light}` (that is, `\difficult` instead of the word `difficult`.  Finally, the tabulation can be recalled with `Moderate tags: \theQTAGmoderate

Difficult tags: \theQTAGdifficult`

Comment: Hi, Steven B. Segletes, many thanks, I understand your method, and it works OK, by the way, I have successfully accumulate the points value, but it is not simple to put this in the comment field, so I think I will add a Answer here. Thanks.

Comment: My answer is added.

Answer (score 1):

With Steven B. Segletes's help, I can accumulate the points of each question for different tags, see the test code below:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}
\newcommand\printqtags{\def\qtag##1{\par\textbf{Tag: (##1)}}}
\newcommand\noprintqtags{\def\qtag##1{}}

\newcounter{QTAGdifficult} 
\newcounter{QTAGmoderate}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\moderate{\addtocounter{QTAGmoderate}{\@points}moderate} 
\newcommand\difficult{\addtocounter{QTAGdifficult}{\@points}difficult}
\makeatother




\unframedsolutions
\printanswers
\printqtags
    \begin{document}
    \section{ABC}
    \begin{questions}

        \question[5] This is question 1 ? \qtag{\difficult, 2009, Light}
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 1
        \end{solution}

        \question[5] This is question 2 \qtag{\moderate, 2019, Sound}
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 2
        \end{solution}
        \question[6] This is Question 3 \qtag{\difficult, 2009, Light}
        \begin{solution}
            This is answer 3
        \end{solution}
\end{questions}

Moderate tags: \theQTAGmoderate 

Difficult tags: \theQTAGdifficult
\end{document}
```

And here is the result pdf screen shot.

[image: image shot of the output pdf]

BTW: I don't know if there is a default point value in `exam` class for each questions. For example, for a true/false question, the default point should be 2 points, so I don't need to put `[2]` in each question. **EDIT** Oh, I see I find the solution, if a question does not specify the point value, it will use the point value of the previous question defined previously.